# Emacs can't find gofmt in go-mode

Tags: emacs, go

I'm trying to use Emacs for golang programming. I downloaded the `go-mode` package and installed it. My `.emacs` is:

```
(require 'go-mode)
```

When I'm opening `*.go` files, `go-mode` enables correctly. But I can't save any `*.go` files because when I'm trying to save `*.go` files I'm getting an error in the minibuffer that says

> `gofmt`program not found.

Golang installed (version 1.3), `gofmt` works from terminal.

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

On OSX I'm usingthe following in .emacs/init.el

```
(use-package exec-path-from-shell
  :ensure t
  :init (exec-path-from-shell-initialize))
```

to insure that Emacs are using the correct path.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have gofmt in your PATH. (echo $PATH) to check, if you can't run gofmt in your shell, it is likely that emacs won't as well.

gofmt on my setup is in $GOBIN/gofmt, but I think it can be as well be in one of the $GOPATH/bin.

If you have it in your path, chances are that you have an emacs configuration that sets the path. Change as needed.

If you installed via a packet manager, chances are that gofmt will be somewhere else. (I think brew puts it in /usr/local/bin)

Small tip when this happen and you really need to save: switch back to text-mode (`M-x text-mode`).

Comment: Emacs' equivalent of `$PATH` is `exec-path`, if you're on OSX they might not have the same elements, see https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell